# Padrão de identificação dos elementos do DOM

Tags: css, html5, design-pattern, front-end

Qual o padrão dos nomes dos identificadores de um HTML , ex :

```
 <form id="alterar-nome-form" th:action="@{/conta/alterarnome}" th:method="put">
 </form>
```

Ou

```
 <form id="alterarNomeForm" th:action="@{/conta/alterarnome}" th:method="put">
 </form>
```

Existem outros padrões ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

não existe uma conversão de nomes para HTML, porém você pode decidir seguir algum conjunto de recomendações, como esta feita pelo [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=ID_and_Class_Name_Delimiters#ID_and_Class_Name_Delimiters)

Se formos seguir o exemplo acima, então o correto seria `alterar-nome-form`

Comment: google é um ótimo exemplo , valeu pela resposta